# How to set videojs player fixed on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I tried to set videoJS player to be fixed on page.

but i can't. Even i set position fixed in videoJS css. nothing happend. please help me.

```
  <div class="video-js-box">
   <video class="video-js"  height="191px" width="246px" controls="controls" 
                     preload="auto" poster="imageUrl">
     <source src="url" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
   </video>
  </div>
```

Script

```
       VideoJS.setupAllWhenReady({
             controlsBelow: true, 
             controlsHiding: true, 
             defaultVolume: 0.85, 
             flashVersion: 9, 
             linksHiding: true
       });
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This css rule fix div.video-js-box in left-top conner

```
.video-js-box{
    position:fixed;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:191px;
    width:246px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a hurry, sorry...

Try wrapping it in a div and set that div to fixed (videoJS sets player position: absolute)

Hope this helps!